# Visual Studio 2010 - Linker error - ODBC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I've been tasked to upgrade an app of ours from VC++6 to VC++ 2010.  After spending a bit of time on it, I've managed to get it to compile successfully.  However, linking fails :(

```
The linker error I'm getting is:
Error   33  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLConfigDataSource@16       referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall CReportPropertyPage4::OnViewReport(void)" (?OnViewReport@CReportPropertyPage4@@IAEXXZ)   <redacted>\ReportPropertyPages.obj
```

While I'll be the first to admit I have zero experience debugging linker errors, I've done some research online to find that I needed to include the proper .lib file for the linker.

So, I went ahead and opened the projects property page and went under linker and added a reference to the .lib under "Additional Dependencies" on the Input tab.

$(ProjectDir)\lib\odbccp32.lib (Note, I did actually make a copy of the .lib into the above folder).

But, no dice.

odbcinst.h is the file that defines the function SQLConfigDataSource (and it's included):

```
BOOL INSTAPI SQLConfigDataSource     (HWND       hwndParent,
                                      WORD       fRequest,
                                      LPCSTR     lpszDriver,
                                      LPCSTR     lpszAttributes);
```

And my associated call to it:

```
            CString strParameters;
            strParameters.Format(
                "DSN=<Redacted> ASCII\0"
                "Description=<Redacted> ASCII\0"
                "CharacterSet=ASCII\0"
                "ColNameHeader=False\0"
                "Format=TabDelimited\0"
                "DEFAULTDIR=%s\0"
                "EXTENSIONS=txt\0\0", strTempDir );

            if( SQLConfigDataSource( NULL, ODBC_ADD_DSN, "Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)",
                strParameters ) )
```

Comment: I think you should put the library name only (i.e. odbccp32.lib) under Additional Dependencies. The folder name should go under Linker/General/Additional LIbrary Directories'

Comment: @john: Gave that a shot.  No difference.

Comment: @john correct. why don't you move the comment as an answer and let OP complete the question :)?